# Cocoa drawing issues

Tags: macos, drawing, quartz-graphics

I'm working on an application that does some drawing on the screen based on information received over the network. 
My problem is that sometimes those events come in at a rate higher than I can draw and I'm experiencing a delay. Now the problem isn't with the delay it's with the type of delay that builds up. 
If I would draw based on events such as clicking with the mouse and dragging this doesn't happen and I assume it's because of the way events are delivered. How could I find out when the view is "ready" to draw again because then I could discard some of the events received over the network and draw just the most recent ones.

Right now I have a transparent window that is on "top" of the window hierarchy. 
Im drawing on an NSImage that is the size of the screen an after each drawing operation I make a setneedsdisplayinrect call to the view in which the drawing happens. When I receive the drawrect call I draw the portion of the image which is included in the dirty rect. 
My attempt of solving this is a bit of a hack since I don't know another way to do it. I set a Boolean to true after each setneedsdisplayinrect and I set it to false in drawrect. If I get a subsequent event to draw on the image I just ignore it of the Boolean is set to true.

What other alternatives of doing this do I have?

I thought of using cashapelayers and modifying their path but I'm not sure how efficient shape layers are once the path gets big. I also thought of using multiple shape layers for different portions of the path that are separated (not continuous) but if I want to clear the drawing and i remove the layers if there are many I noticed a bit of a performance hog. 
The only other way I could think of is drawing with open gl but considering the nature of the OpenGL view (screen size and transparent) I'm not sure how much of a performance issue will this be.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out :)

From the object that managed the network connection I was sending events out using the main dispatch queue. Which from what I understand - I might be wrong about this - can span across multiple iterations of the runloop. What I needed was to dispatch events during each iteration of the run loop and by creating a custom run loop source that would signal the main runloop every time I get a new event over the network connection it greatly improved my performance.